# How do I redirect any url under a folder, keeping the subfolders?

Tags: javascript, html, web, directory, subdirectory

If I have `example.com/example/` with subfolders (for example: `example.com/example/test1/`), how do I redirect from `example.com/redirect/` to `example.com/example/` so that `example.com/redirect/test1/` will redirect to `example.com/example/test1`, without creating a subfolder under `example.com/redirect/` for every subfolder under `example.com/example/` using HTML?

Currently, I have under `example.com/example/` the following `index.html` file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=https://example.com/example/">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm hosting the website via GitHub pages.

Comment: Depends on the server side stack technologies used. Not enough details given in that regard

Comment: I'm using github pages. I've edited the question to include that information.

Comment: So what did your research turn up when you searched for *"github pages redirect"*? Or were you expecting others to do that research for you?

Comment: I've been searching for generic redirect information not specific to github pages.

Comment: Well it will need to be specific to that environment since you don't control the server code